# Chef Integration with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra

I am trying to integrate chef with Jenkins.

My scenario is, I have created few recipes in Chef and want to execute the chef run list through Jenkins. I have installed chef plugin(https://github.com/melezhik/chef-plugin/) in Jenkins and provided the required parameters.
But when I do I build now in Jenkins, it throws me "Host key verification failed error".

I also tried the other way round by just executing "sudo chef-client" as a shell command through Jenkins, even then I receive the same error.

Also I tried putting the Jenkins on the same server where chef node is available, even the issue remains the same.

Can anyone guide me on this.

Comment: Are you able to connect to Chef server using command line? First try that and then try using Jenkins.

Answer (score 6):

The chef integration plugin uses command line `ssh` to connect from Jenkins to the client machine to run `sudo chef-client`. You need to complete this `ssh` connection and a `sudo` command without any password prompts from the Jenkins host, as the user you run Jenkins with first to confirm the Jenkins web interface will be able to do it.

The following is basically the same as the `knife ssh` setup from a chef server to nodes, except you are replacing the chef server/user with the jenkins server/user.

Log into a terminal on your **jenkinshost**, as the Jenkins user.

1. If you don't already have [a private/public key setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys), generate one.

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "jenkinuser@jenkinshost" -N ''
   ```

   Then add the public key `id_rsa.pub` to **chefuser@clienthost**'s `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

   ```
   ssh-copy-id chefuser@clienthost
   ```

   You may need to do this manually if you can't already login to **clienthost** with `ssh`.
2. Clean up any traces of old clients (your error message indicates this might be an issue)

   ```
   ssh-keygen -R clienthost
   ```
3. Test the `ssh` connection, and accept the host key.

   ```
   ssh chefuser@clienthost
   ```
4. Now on **clienthost**, setup `sudo` so `chefuser` can run `chef-client` as `root`

   ```
   visudo
   ```

   Then add the line (Your `chef-client` path might be different)

   ```
   chefuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/chef-client
   ```
5. On **jenkinshost**, confirm `ssh chefuser@clienthost sudo chef-client -v` runs without password prompts.

   ```
   $ ssh chefuser@clienthost sudo /usr/local/bin/chef-client -v
   Chef: 11.16.0
   ```

Once you can do that, the Jenkins plugin should be able to as well.

Every machine you want to run chef-client on from Jenkins will need that public key added and the manual `ssh` connection tested until it works without prompting you.

Unfortunately that Jenkins chef plugin doesn't allow you many config options for the ssh connection so you have to either rely on the one default key for the Jenkins user for everything (`id_rsa`) or say you wanted to use a different key on each host, configure host specific ssh connection details via [`ssh_config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) in `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: To avoid having to accept the host key manually, you may include my answer too, we do that from a windows box, so it tooks us some time to check out. Really complete answer for the rest.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I have followed all the steps given by you but on running the last step it throws "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" error.

Comment: That means `sudo` is still asking for a password on the client. Try just your `sudo` command locally on the client and check the syslog on that client for what is being denied.

Answer (score 0):

"Host key verification failed error"  is quite clear, your jenkins host do not know the target server.

on your jenkins host (as jenkins user) run `ssh-keyscan target_host > ~/.ssh/known_hosts` and then retry and it should work as expected.

Edit: the keyscan could be a task in jenkins itself. For the path I assumed you were running jenkins on a linux box, adapt to jenkins user home path if needed or use %HOME% in place of ~