# Jenkins - unable to copy build artifacts to desired root folder on target machine

Tags: jenkins, ssh

We are just starting with Jenkins for CI - so we're definitely in the newbie phase here.  Here's what we are trying to do:

We are using Publish Over SSH Jenkins plugin to transfer the build artifacts to a target server and into a specific root folder - lets call it /var/mycompany/myapp and this is where the problem is happening.

We have configured the Publish Over SSH plugin to use a key in order to make the connection to the target server. In Manage Jenkins > Configure System > SSH Servers section we have also configured our target ssh server (name/hostname/username/remote folder etc). The connection is successful when tested.

The build job has been configured to "Send artifacts over SSH" as a post-build action. Now this works fine as long as I send the files to my user's home folder location on the target server (ie it will create the necessary ~/var/mycompany/mayapp folder structure and transfer all the files).  BUT - if I change the "Publish over SSH" config to use a Remote Directory of "/" the job fails with the following error:

> SSH: Connecting from host [myjenkins] SSH: Connecting with
>   configuration [stage-tester] ... SSH: Creating session: username
>   [myusername], hostname [x.x.x.x], port [22] SSH: Connecting session
>   ... SSH: Connected SSH: Opening SFTP channel ... SSH: SFTP channel
>   open SSH: Connecting SFTP channel ... SSH: Connected SSH: cd [/] SSH:
>   OK SSH: cd [var] SSH: OK SSH: cd [mycompany] SSH: OK SSH: mkdir
>   [myapp] SSH: FAILED: Message [Permission denied]

At first this made sense to us as the key was created by a specific user who was not a sudoer on the target Linux/Fedora server. So We made the user a member of a sudoer group expecting that this would solve the problem.  It hasn't fixed the issue - we continue to get the "permission denied" error. So the question is how to we go about gaining access to the server root for our user/key?

Any advice is appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end this is the solution I used:

1. Using instructions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739873/chef-integration-with-jenkins) I setup a "jenkins-chef" ssh keypair in the /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh folder and transferred the public key to the jenkins user's authorizedkeys file on my target deployment server.
2. chown the keypair in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh (from step 1) to the "jenkins" user so that the Jenkins ssh server configuration in step 3 can read the key
3. Set up an SSH server reference in Jenkins: under Manage Jenkins > Configure System >  SSH Servers > Added new ssh server ref pointing at my target deployment server using the 'jenkins' username and path to the new key (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/jenkins-chef). Also, we wanted to publish to a folder off of the target server's root (/) folder and it turned out to be important that we specify the "remote directory" as '/' (root)
4. In my Jenkins job I added a new build step using the 'send files or execute commands over ssh' plugin. I configured it to use the ssh server I defined in step 3:

   - source files: **/*
   - exec command: sudo chef-client
   - remote directory: var/my-apps/my-app

Note: If I attempted to specify remote directory with initial root slash (/var/my-apps/my-app) it would copy then to the Jenkins user's home folder and simply create the specified folder structure. That's why specifying '/' in step 3 was important.

That's it from the Jenkins side.  However the first time I tried to run this I got this error:

> SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [sudo chef-client] ... sudo: no
>   tty present and no askpass program specified

This was because I was attempting to run 'sudo' which issues a password challenge on the target server. To avoid this I made the following change to the sudoers file on the target server using the 'visudo' command: at the bottom of the file I added this line to give the jenkins user the ability to run sudo without being prompted for a password:

> jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

Once that was done it all worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with Linux machines, you can try to use the [SCP Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCP+plugin).

In the global configuration, you just have to define the target server like that:

[image]

You can use your jenkins public ssh key to manage the authentication or a user/pwd.

Next, in the Jenkins job, you can create a post build task to copy the relevant artifacts on your server:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bruno - I'll try this. In the scenario you describe would it be a simple matter of transferring the Jenkins's id_rsa.pub to the target machine and adding it to .ssh/authorized keys?

Comment: Exact ! :) (and do not forget to vote and accept for my solution if it works)